# Pixel gap bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

A simple question and probably a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.
As you can see in the example there is a pixel gap between the bottom of the 2 images and the DIV (home-top or home-bottom). 
How do I get rid of that?

```css
.container{
    width:80%;
}

.menu{
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}

.home-top{
    background:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.home-bottom{
    background:#EEE;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.footer{
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    color:white;
}

.txt-left, .img-left{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

.txt-right, .img-right{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    menu
</div>
<div class="home-top">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>home top</h1>
        <div class="txt-left">
            some text goes here.
        </div>
        <div class="img-right">
            <img src="http://www.webtify.be/elkegeraerts/img/elke_geraerts.png" alt="" width="200" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="home-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>home bottom</h1>
        <div class="img-left">
            <img src="http://www.webtify.be/elkegeraerts/img/boek.png" alt="" width="200" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
            some text goes here.
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set "display:block;" on the images.

```
img{
    display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you very much. I know I was missing something!